# difference between "art"and "arts" as a "modifier"

Tags: modifiers

I have seen both of them, but I am wondering which on is considered correct. And, if they both are correct what is the difference between them?

> Art Gallery 
>  Arts Gallery

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you talk about 'art' in general, it's

> An Art Gallery

But then, I've observed that when you talk about 'one particular genre' of an art, it may have several other sub sections. There, 'arts' is more common.

> ***Fine Arts*** Gallery 
>  ***Visual Arts*** Gallery 
>  ***Cultural Arts*** Gallery

---

I'm *not sure*, but it seems when the word 'art' has an adjective before it, it's 'arts'. Those latter examples prove it.

Comment: Maybe that's just to avoid the misinterpretations "a fine gallery of art", "a cultural gallery of art", a visual gallery of art" (although it would be hard to imagine an art gallery that wasn't visual!)

Comment: A great observation, +1. I wanted to post a link for a Google ngram that proves your point, but it has more than 700 characters (it's huge). Anyway, if you are interested you might try to graph these phrases: '* art gallery, * arts gallery' and see the results :-)

Comment: Oh thanks @Lucky. I did not go through it, but now I'll :)

Comment: Maulik,  Liberty Fine Art Gallery,  Jackson Fine Art Gallery,  Visual Art Gallery Auckland, Sawtooth School for visual art,  Doral Cultural Art Gallery, etc.

Comment: Correct, but then they are followed by a proper noun in most of the cases. **Jackson**, **Liberty**, **Sawtooth**, **Doral** etc. Again, as I said, it's not incorrect. @Khan